# Message.Edit Function Error With Discord Javascript Bot

Tags: javascript, scripting, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to assemble a bot that can retrieve google image search results into an embed that 'refreshes/changes' pages to the next image/result. Right now, this script has a reaction menu that pops up, but upon clicking it, I get an error that says:

```
       message.edit(gglembed(currentIndex))
                                             ^

TypeError: gglembed is not a function
```

Code:

```
    case 'rimg':
        var parts = message.content.split(' ');
        var search = parts.slice(1).join(" ");
        var options = {
            url: "http://results.dogpile.com/serp?qc=images&q=" + search,
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                "Accept": "text/html",
                "User-Agent": "Chrome"
            }
        };
        request(options, function(error, response, responseBody) {


                $ = cheerio.load(responseBody); // load responseBody into cheerio (jQuery)

                var links = $(".image a.link");


                var urls = new Array(links.length).fill(0).map((v, i) => links.eq(i).attr("href"));
                var imgresults = urls[Math.floor(Math.random() * urls.length)];
                console.log(urls);
                const gglembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()

                    .setTitle('Image Search Results from  ' + message.author.tag)
                    .setImage(imgresults);
                message.channel.send({
                    embed: gglembed
                }).then(imgsearchembedr => {
                        if (imgresults.length <= 2) {
                            return;
                        }
                        message.react('➡️')
                        const filter = (reactions, user) => true;
                        const collector = message.createReactionCollector(
                            // only collect left and right arrow reactions from the message author
                            (reaction, user) => ['⬅️', '➡️'].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === message.author.id,
                            // time out after a minute
                            {
                                time: 60000
                            });

                    let currentIndex = urls + 1;
                    collector.on('collect', reaction => {
                        message.reactions.removeAll().then(async () => {
                            reaction.emoji.name === '⬅️' ? currentIndex -= 10 : currentIndex += 10
                            message.edit(gglembed(currentIndex))
                            if (currentIndex !== 0) {
                                await message.react('⬅️')
                            } else {
                                if (currentIndex + 10 < urls.length) message.react('➡️')
                            }
                        })
                    })
                })
        })
break;
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: well, it says it right there. `gglembed` is not a function and therefore doesn't take any arguments.

Comment: @WorthyAlpaca yeah, it is a direct error. I am just confused, because discord.js documentation says it can be an embed; see: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/MessageEditOptions
How would I make this embed a function and call it here? Just seems weird to me, but I'm learning.

Comment: yes, `message.edit` can be an embed however the embed it'sself is not a function and that is where the error in question comes from. `gglembed(currentIndex)` <- the `()` make it a function and in this case the error. See [here](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html#resending-and-editing) for help on how to edid embeds.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to pass along a parameter to your MessageEmbed? That doesn't work. To edit the message with the embed you would have to do `message.edit(gglembed)`. Am I right that you want to somehow edit your embed based on what that variable `currentIndex` holds? If that's the case you have to explain what that variable should do, since I can't see that in your code (I can't see how the variable should impact your embed...)

Edit:
Alright, to react to the embed message you have to do the following: (I replaced just the important part of the code)

````js
//create a variable embedMessage which holds the message sent by the bot
const embedMessage = await message.channel.send({
                   embed: gglembed
               }).then(imgsearchembedr => {
                   if (imgresults.length <= 2) {
                       return;
                   }
               });
               embedMessage.react('➡️')
               const filter = (reactions, user) => true;
               const collector = embedMessage.createReactionCollector(
               // only collect left and right arrow reactions from the message author
                   (reaction, user) => ['⬅️', '➡️'].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === message.author.id,
                   // time out after a minute
                   {
                       time: 60000
                   }
               );
               let currentIndex = urls + 1;
               collector.on('collect', reaction => {
                   embedMessage.reactions.removeAll().then(async () => {
                       reaction.emoji.name === '⬅️' ? currentIndex -= 10 : currentIndex += 10
                       await embedMessage.edit(gglembed)
                       if (currentIndex !== 0) {
                           await embedMessage.react('⬅️')
                       } else {
                           if (currentIndex + 10 < urls.length) message.react('➡️')
                       }
                  })
              })```
````

Comment: Ok, thanks for pointing that out to me. Can't believe I didn't notice that. 
I want the embed to edit and post the new URLS result, which I'm adding +1 too. You can see I have it grayed out right now in the version I've posted, but in my own it's in there now.


currentindex isn't the issue now, actually, the reaction adds to my own message instead of the embed, any idea why that is?